# API POST Call throws 401 error when used pytest

Tags: python, api, pytest

I am performing the API Testing and using the pytest framework. Test is failing all the time with 401 error. Couldn't figure out what was the issue.

## Here is the code :

```
    import requests
    import json,jsonpath
    import urllib3
    import constants
    urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    
    # variables
    dumpFile = "somepath"
    url = "someUrl"
    headers = {'Authorization' : constants.consts['siteToken'],
           'accept':'application/json',
           'content-type':'application/json'}
    #siteToken = 'Bearer jwt token'
    
    # read json input file
    input_file = open("json file path", 'r')
    json_input = input_file.read()
    request_json = json.loads(json_input)
    
    # make POST request with JSON Input Body
    r = requests.post(url, request_json, headers=headers)
    
    # Verification of the response
    assert r.status_code == 200

 def test_json_result():
    # fetch header from response
    print(r.headers.get("Date"))
    
    # parse response to JSON Format
    response_json = json.loads(r.text)
    
    # validate response using Json Path
    name = jsonpath.jsonpath(response_json, 'name')
    print(name)
```

Comment: Probably because headers variable with authentication token is not included in the request.

Comment: Thank you, I did it by adding this way : r = requests.post(url, request_json, , headers=headers). Now, the program is throwing the 400 error and intermittently I am getting the error : b'{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid request payload JSON format"}'. Any suggestions ? Is there a specific way to build the json for pytest ?

Comment: Not enough details there to be sure, make sure the url passed to the request is correct using a debugger or `print(r.url)`

Comment: I have it solved last evening. It is because of my request building. It was supposed to be json=request_json and not just request_json.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by just putting json=your_payload.

```
        import requests
        import json,jsonpath
        import urllib3
        import constants
        urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

        # variables
        dumpFile = "somepath"
        url = "someUrl"
        headers = {'Authorization' : constants.consts['siteToken'],
               'accept':'application/json',
               'content-type':'application/json'}
        #siteToken = 'Bearer jwt token'

        # read json input file
        input_file = open("json file path", 'r')
        json_input = input_file.read()
        request_json = json.loads(json_input)

    def test_json_result():
# make POST request with JSON Input Body
        r = requests.post(url, json=request_json, headers=headers)

        # Verification of the response
        assert r.status_code == 200
        # fetch header from response
        print(r.headers.get("Date"))

        # parse response to JSON Format
        response_json = json.loads(r.text)

        # validate response using Json Path
        name = jsonpath.jsonpath(response_json, 'name')
        print(name)
```